# Problem calling Ajax with special chars in parameter data

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm using this function to apply `JQuery.autocomplete` to a textbox widget:

```
function GetData(dest_widget) {
    dest_widget.autocomplete({
        minLength: 3,
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Service/WSDataService.asmx/GetData",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: "{'filter':'" + request.term + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    var _data_array = data.d.split("<br />");
                    response(_data_array);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("GetData() error" + result);
                }
            })
        }
    });
}
```

It works fine unless I try to input special chars (like `'`) in textbox... In such case I got this error:

> Object {Message: "The passed object is not valid. Expected ':' o
> '}'…", StackTrace: "   in
> System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptOb…", ExceptionType:
> "System.ArgumentException"}

Looks like I need to encode widget value before invoking ajax .. I tried with:

```
data: "{'filter':'" + encodeURIComponent(request.term) + "'}",
```

and also tried changing `contentType` but I had no success in both cases.

Comment: try with [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)

Comment: where you suggest to use such call? I mean... `encodedURIComponent()` call in my example it's not called at all. The error seems to be rised in the parameter passage of `source` function... btw I need to change  `contentType ` ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was really simple to fix.
It seems that `encodeURIComponent()` was not so strict in encoding: in my case `'` char was not encoded after all (despite what [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) says). Anyway Mozilla add a suggestion to use:

```
function fixedEncodeURIComponent(str) {
  return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!'()*]/g, function (c) {
    return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
  });
}
```

To properly encode `'` chars (among other). It sounds a little confusing to me  but by the way it works...